# Is there a way to diagnose *where* comms to a port on a windows machine is being blocked?

Tags: firewall, routing, port-forwarding, windows-firewall

I am developing a system that comprises an email server.

I have so far been unable to connect on port 25 (using telnet), despite having checked the following are set up correctly. Connections to port 80 work fine:

- Firewall exceptions (Windows and Router firewalls, also tried with
  firewalls turned off)
- Port forwarding for port 25

Is there anything I can do to help me verify *where* comms is being blocked. Obviously tracert can't be used for a specific port.

Is it common for ISP's to block inbound traffic on a port? (Virgin Media in this case).

Comment: Inbound I don't know, but ISPs tend to be really wary of port 25 traffic in general, and for good reason.

Comment: There is no way of verifying where the port gets dropped. Are you seeing port 25 open on the server via `netstat -abn`? Can you `telnet localhost 25` and get a response?

Comment: Yes telnet localhost 25 does get a response, albeit blank. Port 25 does show up with netstat -abn.

Comment: Also works from another PC on my internal network...